# How can you truly protect your Javascript/JQuery source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I mean all the code is rendered as text files written to the client.

Besides of obfuscate and uglify your source code? What can be done to trully protect your JavaScript assets.

Comment: I use http://jslock.it/  uses obfuscation with domain locking script.

Comment: You don't.  If it needs to be protected, keep the logic on the server.

Answer (score 2):

**YOU CAN'T**

You shouldn't even try to obfuscate (not talking about minifying nor compilation) your code because obfuscation  makes interpreters less likely to optimize your code. javascript code is not meant to be protected. you should focus on protecting your data not your output or client side code.